# Should registration email for a website greet with "Congratulation"?

Tags: usability, gui-design, interaction-design, user-behavior

I have created a new account.At the start up. I received a Congratulation email saying. You are now part of this site. Doesn't it look strange?

Mail Format:

Congratulations!Thanks for registering on the world's most interactive Social Learning Network.We need to confirm your email address to start.

Comment: In the header you say "invitation email", do you mean that someone has invited you to some site? Why would invitation say "you are part of this site", unless you yourself have signed up?

Comment: Why does it  look strange?

Comment: Please, provide more details. Is it an invitation to use site's features after registration or an invitation to register to some site you have never seen? In the latter, I think it's very unfortunate, unless you have won some additional value (maybe due to being invited by a friend of you). If the site is an exclusive one (like invitation to participate in private beta for some premium tool), well, it may be also some reason they have used this word. In other cases I wouldn't say they should use it.

Comment: I think that the formatting and wording of email messages from your system is part of the UX, and thus is a valid question as such. NN group even created a complete report on email-related issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your unease about the wording. Congratulating someone implies that they have accomplished some feat/challenge, and could easily be construed as "over the top". It also could be seen (by some) as self-aggrandizing -- "CONGRATULATIONS on being one of my customers. You're so lucky!".

The goal of these kinds of emails is to create a sense of being welcoming and friendly. Sticking to the KISS principle, perhaps *welcoming* language is more appropriate (and less likely to be seen as "over the top") than *congratulatory* language.

Answer (score 1):

Saying "congratulations" isn't entirely necessary unless the user has done that deserves a congratulations. Unless a user had to meet a certain criteria to join the site or they had to be invited, saying "congratulations" to someone for just signing up is a bit over the top.